# How we can calculate the acceleration of a body using the second law of newton

Tags: physics

If we hit a box (mass = $2$ kg, at rest, without friction) with a force of $2$ Newtons, how do we calculate the acceleration of the box upon hitting using the second law of newton?

## I tried this:
$f = m*a$

$a = \frac{f}{m}$

=>
$a = \frac{2}{2} =1$ m/s^2

but that not right because the acceleration in the beginning must be a bigger number.

Comment: Why must the acceleration be a "big number"? $F = ma$. $2 = 2 \times ?$ Also, $1$ m/s² = $3.6$ kmph/s. In $100$ s ($1$ minute $40$ seconds), the object would attain a speed of $360$ kmph. That's a "big number", *cogito*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. The applied force is so small that acceleration in the beginning will be small too.

Given that,

Mass = 2kg,

Applied force = 2N

We know that,
$Acceleration = Applied force/ Mass$

So, acceleration will be = $2/2$   $m/s^2$ = $1$  $m/s^2$

Comment: how 1m/s^2 and when we hit the box the velocity changes from 0 to a specific velocity in a very very short time?

Comment: Your applied force is too small compared to the mass of the box. So, it isn't possible to have a great acceleration. In 1st second, the velocity will change from 0 to 1$m/s$

Comment: thank you i understand now, can u tell me how to calculate the  initial velocity please at hiting time?
i tried: a=f/M; then with integration => v(t) - v(0) = f/m * t; => v(0) = f/m * t +v(t), but we can't here

Comment: I saw your post, if I can solve this I will answer that into that post.

Comment: thank you .....